# how to use smart pointers in this case

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++17, smart-pointers

Is there any better way of writing this code using modern c++ and smart pointers? I want to avoid dealing with dreaded pointer to pointer type syntax and manual memory management by explicit calls to new and delete.

```
#include <map>

void GetData(std::map<int, int>** data);

int main()
{
    std::map<int, int>* data = nullptr;
    GetData(&data);

    delete data;
    return 0;
}


void GetData(std::map<int, int>** data)
{
    *data = new std::map<int, int>
    {
        {1,1},
        {2,1}
    };

}
```

Comment: Is there a reason the main `data` is allocated on the heap, or are you just coming from a Java/C# background and are doing it out of habit?

Comment: You should learn to pass stuff by reference instead of by pointer, and like what @Frank said there is no reason to dynamically allocate the map at all in the first place. All you have to do is `std::map<int, int> data{{1, 1}, {2, 1}}`.

Comment: @FeiXiang, well, I'm giving OP the benefit of the doubt here, this is a MCVE, so they might actually need dynamic allocation. I feel the question can't be properly answered we know whether it's intentional or not.

Comment: I was trying to contrive a simpler example of the scenario. I probably didn't do enough justice with my question. The scenario is that a data structure needs to be populated in a different place then in the caller but called needs to consume that data. I would like to do it with minimum overhead possible. I probably can post a different question with more clear example of the question

Comment: @BKS Sounds like you might be looking for a reference. If you edit in a better example it would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There absolutely is a better way of writing this, and you don't need pointers at all!

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream> // just for printing using std::cout

auto GetData()
{
    return std::map<int, int>
    {
        {1,1},
        {2,1}
    };    
}

int main()
{
    const auto data = GetData();
    for (auto d : data)
    {
        std::cout << d.first << ", " << d.second << "\n";
    }
}
```

No more ugly pointer syntax, no more manually allocating and deallocating memory, you don't need to worry about anything.

Comment: how many copies of map will get created with this solution? 1 or more?

Comment: @BKS, Have you heard of copy elision?

Comment: @BKS don't worry about that

Comment: With all respect, why does it matter? It's likely just one object will get created, but try not to concern yourself with it. Write readable code and let the compiler do what it's good at.

Comment: This is the best answer, lol @ downvote. In C++17 it is guaranteed that there is no copy, the map in constructed directly in `data`. (But you should do `auto&&d` rather than `auto d`)

Comment: @BKS Most compilers will elide the copy so only one will be created. On the off chance that doesn't happen the value will be *moved* out of the function which is very efficient.

Comment: @miradulo sorry that's what I mean. Others have said it best, I simply meant only one object would be created, not one object and one copy